# Custom image in Django template via static

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I am programming a website powered by Django 1.6.3. Under news you always see a big story and on the side recent articles. Therefore, I used Bootstrap 3 and wrote a static html page serving my requirements.

Now I would like to program the logic behind this. I save all my files under `static` that consists of the folders `css`, `fonts` (from Bootstrap), `img` and `js`. The image folder has some subfolder e.g. news. To create a new entry on the news page I would like to open the admin page, add a news_entry and select one image that should be under the titel. How is it possible to include the image in the page? My approach was:

```
<img src="{% static {{ news.image_name }} %}" class="img-title">
```

Unfortunately I get an parsing error. Image_name is a property of my news model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the `url` attribute of your `image_name`.

Try:

```
<img src="{{ news.image_name.url }}" class="img-title">
```

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850535/how-to-get-an-imagefield-url-within-a-template).

Comment: No, this doesn't work. I got an error message saying: Could not parse the remainder: '{{' from '{{'.

Comment: Edited. Take out the `static` url tag. Note that ImageFields are generally saved under your `MEDIA_ROOT`, not your `STATIC_ROOT`. Regardless, you don't need a media or static tag in template.