# How to show image from django database in a html page?

Tags: html, django

I have uploaded images in django database, but I'm not able to show those images on the HTML page.

The image name is being fetched but it is not being shown. This is my code:

**models.py**

```
image=models.FileField(upload_to='images',blank=True)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Movie, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    filename=self.image.url
```

**results.html**

```
<table>
  <td>
    <tr>{% for i in p %}</tr>
    <tr>{{i.movie_name}}</tr>
    <tr>{{i.description}}</tr>
    <tr>{{i.release_date}}</tr>
    <tr>{{i.ticket_price}}</tr>
    <img src="{{i.image}}"/>
    <tr>{% endfor %}</tr>
  </td>
</table>
```

Please tell me what changes I have to make in the **views.py** file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get an ImageField URL within a template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850535/how-to-get-an-imagefield-url-within-a-template) (the question asks about `ImageField` but it is the same for `FileField`. You should consider using `ImageField` anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

`<img src="{{i.image}}"/>`

in your **results.html**, use this :

`<img src="{{ i.image.url }}"/>`