# How do I get Image from parent model to the child model related with foreign key

Tags: django

I have design a parent model which works fine. Parent model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    present_position=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    organization= models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)    
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=70, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    photo= ResizedImageField(size=[100, 100],crop=['middle', 'center'],upload_to='persons/%Y/%m/%d/',null=True,
        blank=True,
        editable=True,
        help_text="Person Picture")
```

I have child model which produce executive committee members:

```
class ExecMember(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    committee_position = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    rank = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    member_start_date = models.DateField(blank=True)
    member_end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

From child model I want to produce Executive Committee members list containing their related photo from Person model.

So far I tried:

In template:

```
{% for execomember in object_list %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{forloop.counter}}.</td>
            <td>{{execomember.name}}<br>
            {{execomember.committee_position}}</td>
            <td><a href="{% url 'member:person-list'  %}">
            <img src="{{ person.photo_url|default_if_none:'#'}}" class="img-responsive">
        </a></td>
            <td>
            {{execomember.member_start_date }}<br>
           {{execomember.member_end_date}}
            </td>
            <td>
             {{execomember.is_active}}<br>

            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

In views:

```
class ExeCommListView(generic.ListView):
    model = ExecMember
    context_object_name = 'execomembers'
```

In urls:

```
url(r'^execomember/$', views.ExeCommListView.as_view(), name='execomember-list'),
```

But this gives all the fields values of child model correctly. Only photo not shown.

How do I get photo from parent model to ExecMember model? 
Thanks.

Comment: Why call to `person.photo_url` in template ? It shouldn't be `person.photo.url` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get an ImageField URL within a template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850535/how-to-get-an-imagefield-url-within-a-template)

Comment: It is my photo_url which I defined in the Person model. Even I do with person.photo.url. same result.

Comment: In your model you only have `photo= ResizedImageField`. You should edit your model then.

Comment: This field worked fine in Person model. I already uploaded photo correctly in Person model. I only need to call photo in Execmember model.

Comment: Try `<img src="{{ execomember.name.photo_url|default_if_none:'#'}}" class="img-responsive">`

Comment: That's work. Thanks @4140tm .