# Could not display image uploaded template

Tags: django

I'm in model author create a field for upload picture for my author.
But when I want to go inside template, it doesn't show any.

My code in template

```
<img src="{{ post.author.pic }}" />
```

and in model author :

```
pic = models.ImageField(upload_to = func.upload_location, null = True, blank = True)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get an ImageField URL within a template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850535/how-to-get-an-imagefield-url-within-a-template)

Answer (score -1):

use this

`{{ post.author.pic.url }}`