# I cant display an image on Django template

Tags: python, html, css, django

Am working with django 1.5.4 with python 2.7  I have tried to figure out what is the cause of this image to show like this 
**view.py**

```
def single(request,slug):
product = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
images = product.productimage_set.all()
categories = product.category_set.all()

context = {
    "product":product,
    "categories":categories,
    "edit":True,
    "images":images,
}
return render_to_response("products/single.html", context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**and the single.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h1>{{ product }}</h1>
{% for abc in images %}
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ abc.image }}" />
{% endfor %}
<ul>
{% for category in categories %}
<li>{{ category }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

{% if edit %}
<a href="#">Edit this product</a>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

But it shows is this 
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TCQ7.jpg)

please help out with this issue is the problem form code or ?
models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True,blank=True)
title = models.CharField(max_length=180)
description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=2)
sale_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=2,null=True,blank=True)
slug = models.SlugField()
order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False,auto_now=True)
active = models.BooleanField(default=True)


def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.title)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-order']

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="products/image/")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120,null=True,blank=True)
    featured_image = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False,auto_now=True)


def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.title)
```

Comment: `abc.image.url`

Comment: and why so old django? better to update it

Comment: Add models in your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get an ImageField URL within a template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850535/how-to-get-an-imagefield-url-within-a-template)

Comment: @ Bear Brown  abc.image.url does the same

Comment: Some times it may not work with media folder.Just move your images to assets or static folder and use as given.<img src="{% static 'images/logo.png' %}" alt="" class="img-padding">

Comment: Can you right click on the image in the browser and check what the link of broken image is? Paste it here.

Comment: Thank you all i discovered the problem was on the url for media files url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root':settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),

Answer (score 1):

For django 1.5.4 you have to setting.py and edit MEDIA_ROOT

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))),"static","media")

MEDIA_URL = '/media/' ###This depends on the location of your media files### As this was for the location of my files
```

and on **urls.py**

```
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root':settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
```