# Static media images are not displaying in Django

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles, django-media

I am working on an online bookstore app. I have a book details page that displays book information in a table, including the book cover image. I am having an issue where the images display correctly when I runserver, however a team member is unable to get the images to display after pulling my code from Github.

all books template:

```
{%  extends 'bookstore/main.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load static %}
from .models import Product

{% block content %}
  <div class="container">  
      <p>
        <h1 style="text-align:center;color:green;"> 
            GeekText Complete List of Books<br>
        </h1>

        <h3 style="text-align:center;color:green;">
            Click the Book Name for More Details
        </h3>
      </p>
      
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped tablesorter">  
            <thead>  
                <tr>  
                    <th scope="col">ID #</td>  
                    <th scope="col">Book Title</td>  
                    <th scope="col">Genre</th>
                    <th data-sorter="false" scope="col">Cover Image</td>  
                    <th scope="col">Author</td> 
                </tr>  
            </thead>  
              
            <tbody>  
                {% for item in items %}
                <tr>  
                    <td scope="row">{{ item.id }}</td>   
                    <td><a href="{% url 'book_details_with_pk' id=item.id %}">{{ item.name }}</a></td>   
                    <td>{{ item.genre }}</td>
                    <td><img src="{% static item.image %}" width="75" height="100"/></td> 
                    <td>{{ item.author }}</td>    
                    
                    <td><a href="{% url 'addtocart' item.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">Add To Cart</a>
                </tr>  
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>  
        </table>
        {% endblock %}
      </div>  
    </div> 
    </div>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.db.models import Q
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView, View
from .models import Product
from .models import Author
from .models import Genre
from .models import CartProduct
from .models import Cart
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger

def all_books(request, id=None):
    item = Product.objects.get(id=id)
    context = {
        'items': Product.objects.all().order_by('id'),
        'id': item.id, 
        'name': item.name,
        'cover': item.image,
        'author': item.author,
    }
    
    return render(request,'bookstore/all_books.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('all_books/', views.all_books, name="all_books"),
    path('book_details/', views.book_details, name="book_details"),
    path(r'^book_details/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.book_details, name="book_details_with_pk"),
    path('books/', views.books, name="books"),
    path(r'^book_author/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.book_author, name="book_author"),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crispy_forms',
    'apps.users',
    'apps.bookstore',
    'django_filters',
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model): # model to create table on database products

    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre,related_name='products',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author',related_name='authors',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/media',blank=True)
    image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/%Y/%m/%d',blank=True)
    image3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/%Y/%m/%d',blank=True)
    publisher = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    release_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')` Add this line to settings.py and try if it works

Answer (score 0):

`models.ImageField` - these are **media** files, not **static**.

They get [affected](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.storage) by settings: **MEDIA_ROOT, MEDIA_URL**

What the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#media-root) say about MEDIA_ROOT:

> Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold **user-uploaded files**.
>
> Warning
>
> MEDIA_ROOT and STATIC_ROOT must have different values.

And media files should not be mixed with static files in folders.

**Media** files should be referenced like that

```
<img src="{{ item.image.url }}" />
```

here `image` - your field name, for `image2` it would be `item.image2.url`

You have mixed **static** and **media** files  by these field options:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/media',blank=True)
image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/%Y/%m/%d',blank=True)
image3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/%Y/%m/%d',blank=True)
```

now some of media files (image2, image3) are reachable through **MEDIA_URL** (because they belong to **MEDIA_ROOT** folder), some (image) are not - because they belong to **STATIC_ROOT** folder. You have found a workaround - you reference `image` field by `"{% static item.image %}"` trick which can help overcoming wrong setup but is also not a right way.

Also, your teammate might be having troubles with accessing "static" files because the term `static` is being misused. Again, files stored in the `ImageField`s are not *static* and are not part of your project. They are supposed to be uploaded by users and never stored in git. If you want to share them - you have to share files already uploaded to your local `/media/...` folders somehow.

Static files are/can be something like:

- favicon.ico
- main.css
- robots.txt
- popup.js
- top_banner.jpg

So:

- change `upload_to` for `image` field
- move already uploaded files to new folder (under `media` folder), update file paths in the db
- fix the way you reference these **media** files in templates to `...image.url`

see also:

- [how to access imagefield contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850535/how-to-get-an-imagefield-url-within-a-template)
- [about static files options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66437690/django-html-template-cant-find-static-css-and-js-files/66439076#66439076)