# How do I use product image in html background url of a div?. Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-media

I don't know how I can display a product-image inside my template.
The image needs to go inside a background-url of a div, using static isn't a option, cause then its not coming form models.

**Html**

```
 ....
    {% if products %}
      {% for product in products %}
    
       <div class="product-grid" style="background-image:url({% static 'images/product-1.jpg' %});">
         <div class="inner">
            <p>
               <a href="{% url 'single_product' %}" class="icon"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
               <a href="{% url 'single_product' %}" class="icon"><i class="icon-eye"></i></a>
           </p>
         </div>
      </div>
        {{ product.title }}
        ${{ product.price }}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
   ....
```

**Models**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ....
    photo_main = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**View**

```
def shop(request):
    products = Product.objects.order_by('-upload_date').filter(is_published=True)

    context = {'products': products}
    return render(request, 'shop/shop.html', context)
```

**Settings**

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'ecom/static')
]
```

Please give me a answer if you know how to do this? see image for more info

Comment: Please edit your question and replace link/screenshot of your code with the code itself. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Interesting. Please take a look at the answer for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66833381/static-media-images-are-not-displaying-in-django/66834540#66834540

Comment: Same for your case: these are not **static** files, but **media** files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files stored in `ImageField` are **media** files, not **static**.

They are managed by `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` settings and must be referenced in templates like that:

```
style="background-image:url('{% product.photo_main.url %}');"
```

note additional single quotes around {}