# Wrong image URL on django

Tags: python, django, image, url, django-staticfiles

I am new to django and am having an issue with images. When i stay when I view the main page of my blog with all the articles everything is fine with the images, but as soon as I want to view one specific article, then the problems with the images start due to the wrong url/

**urls.py (project)**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('main.urls')),

] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *


def index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    topics = Topic.objects.all()
    return render(request, "index.html", {"posts": posts, "topics": topics})

def post(request, postinf):
    post = Post.objects.get(title=postinf)


    return render(request, "post.html", {"post": post} )
```

**urls.py (app)**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('blog', views.index),
    path('blog/<str:postinf>/', views.post, name="postdetail"),
]
```

**settings.py**

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "main/static/",
    
]

STATIC_URL = 'main/static/'
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_avatar = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="main/static/images")


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)


class Post(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name="Название поста")
    post_text = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING)
    time = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    post_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="main/static/images")


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**+no problem on the main page (http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog) with images

- when i go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/post/ get this error on console and no images**

```
Not Found: /blog/post/main/static/images/istockphoto-10252.jpg
[19/Apr/2023 01:28:00] "GET /blog/post/main/static/images/istockphoto-10252.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2699
```

Comment: Please take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66833381/static-media-images-are-not-displaying-in-django/66834540#66834540

Comment: Also add the image url which opens fine on `/blog` page so others will be able to see the difference and show template code where you try refer to this image.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Django uses `STATIC_URL` to determine the url to use for the static files.

However your `STATIC_URL` is `main/static` which is a relative URL. This just needs to be prefixed with a `/` if your URL follows the pattern `example.com/main/static/file.jpg`

```py
# In settings.py
STATIC_URL = '/main/static/'
```

Comment: Ok, i will try it later