# Django 404 image for profile picture

Tags: django

I have added a new attribute to my django model that includes a imagefield attribute for profile pictures:

Models.py:

```
class AvailableDrinks(models.Model):
    drink_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    store_name = models.ForeignKey('Stores', on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1200)
    drinksSlug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="static/media/images/drinkPhotos", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.drink_name
```

Views.py:

```
class DrinksView(generic.DetailView):
    template_name = "drinks.html"
    context_object_name = "drinks"
    model = AvailableDrinks
    slug_url_kwarg = 'drinksSlug'

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(AvailableDrinks, drinksSlug=self.kwargs['drinksSlug'])

    def get_queryset(self):
        return AvailableDrinks.objects.all()

class StoreView(generic.DetailView):
    template_name = "caffeine-stores.html"
    model = Stores
    context_object_name = 'stores'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'slug'
```

Url.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", HomeView.as_view(), name="home"),
    path('<slug:slug>/', StoreView.as_view(), name="stores"),
    path("<slug:slug>/<slug:drinksSlug>/", DrinksView.as_view(), name="drinks"),
    path("<int:account_id>/select_drinks/", views.select_drink, name="select")
]
print(settings.DEBUG)
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

MEDIA_URL = ''
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR
```

I have printed out my directories to make sure that they are properly pointing to the image files. I have also insured that they are uploading correctly from the admin page yet I still get an error: ""GET /static/media/images/drinkPhotos/icepop_drink.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 404 1888". Am I just missing something simple? I originally was getting a file attribute error saying that there was no file associated with the imagefield but I got around that with some fiddling. Now the website displays but the images revert to their alt text and don't display.

Comment: `/static/media/images/drinkPhotos/icepop_drink.jpeg` Is that the correct url for the image?  If you look in the folder on your hard drive, is the image there?

Comment: Yes John Gordon I have for sure verified that the files exist at that url.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66833381/static-media-images-are-not-displaying-in-django/66834540#66834540

Answer (score 0):

The [ImageFIeld](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#imagefield) model inherits from the [FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#filefield). The [upload_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#filefield) argument is appended to the MEDIA_ROOT defined in your settings.

In Django, the static files (.js, .css, templates, etc.) are collected by the framework and contained in the STATIC_ROOT directory. The media files are uploaded by users--for example, an image. These will be stored in the MEDIA_ROOT, not under the STATIC_ROOT.

Based on your settings, the MEDIA_ROOT is the project's root directory--I'd recommend changing it to "media/" or something along those lines to prevent the project's root from being polluted by user uploads. It may also have security implications, but that's a speculation that I haven't tested.

In short, yes, you're looking in the wrong location for the image, so you're getting a 404. I'd expect to find them in `/images/drinkPhotos/`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @EvenOttinger thanks for your timely response, unfortunately that didn't seem to work, instructions were slightly unclear to me. I understand that the Media_root and Static_root are different yes. But the images exist in that specific url. I am more confused on how to tell my server to find the images at the specific urls. I have confirmed with a print that the media root and media url are the same. But my server still cannot find the images.

Comment: @Banderson98908 you can retrieve the ImageField object from the database and reference the `url` attribute. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#filefield

Comment: I have been referencing the URL attribute and have gotten the image to display but only after inputting in the src "127.0.0.1:8000:Home/{{ drink.drink_photo.url}}".

Comment: Try adding a `/` at the end of the URL

Comment: can't say that worked either, seems to only work when putting the IP I am running the server on and the Home path, which is the main URL for my app. Adding / after the URL doesn't seem to work, I have also checked my permissions on the files and that seems to be in working order as well. When I go to Home/media/image/whatever.jpeg, that seems to work. My MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') and my MEDIA_URL = '/media/'.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that I had been putting the `urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` within my app's `URL.py` and needed to put it in my project's `URL.py`. Pretty silly mistake but eventually got it luckily.