# When I am filtering the product but when I run the project I don't get the images

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

When I am filtering the product but when I run the project I don't get the images

If I change the code Product.objects.filter(slug=slug)
To
replce the code with Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
the I am facing this type off error in my trminal

Django 'Product' object is not iterable

**Views.py**

```py
def product_detail(request, slug):
    try:
        product = Product.objects.filter(slug=slug)
        context = {
            'product': product,
        }
        return render(request, 'buyer/product_details.html', context)
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        return render(request, 'buyer/product_details.html', {'error': 'No data found.'})
```

**URLs.py**

```py
path('product/<slug:slug>', views.product_detail, name="product_detail"),
```

**Models.py**

```
    class Product(models.Model):
        total_quantity = models.IntegerField()
        availability = models.IntegerField()
        feature_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/Product_image')
        product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        price = models.IntegerField()
        discount = models.IntegerField()
        product_information = RichTextField()
        model_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        categories = models.ForeignKey(MainCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        tags = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        description = RichTextField()
        section = models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
        slug = models.SlugField(default='', max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.product_name

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            from django.urls import reverse
            return reverse("product_detail", kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

        class Meta:
            db_table = "buyer_Product"


    def create_slug(instance, new_slug=None):
        slug = slugify(instance.product_name)
        if new_slug is not None:
            slug = new_slug
        qs = Product.objects.filter(slug=slug).order_by('-id')
        exists = qs.exists()
        if exists:
            new_slug = "%s-%s" % (slug, qs.first().id)
            return create_slug(instance, new_slug=new_slug)
        return slug


    def pre_save_post_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        if not instance.slug:
            instance.slug = create_slug(instance)


    pre_save.connect(pre_save_post_receiver, Product)


    class ProductImage(models.Model):
        product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        image_url = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/Product_image')

        def __str__(self):
            return self.product.product_name
```

**HTML Page**

```
    <div class="product-image-slider">

            {% for i in product.productimage_set.all %}
                <figure class="border-radius-10">
                    <img src="{{ i.image_url }}" alt="product image"/>
                </figure>
            {% endfor %}


        </div>
        <!-- THUMBNAILS -->
        <div class="slider-nav-thumbnails">
            {% for i in product.productimage_set.all %}
                <div><img src="{{ i.image_url }}" alt="product image"/></div>
            {% endfor %}

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Gallery -->
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get an ImageField URL within a template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850535/how-to-get-an-imagefield-url-within-a-template)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `.url`

```
{% for i in product.productimage_set.all %}
<figure class="border-radius-10">
    <img src="{{ i.image.url }}" alt="product image"/>
</figure>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

that's because:

*Product.objects.get(slug=slug)* returns a single object type porduct. and one single object is not iterable

and

*Product.objects.filter(slug=slug)* returns a Queryset[] of products (list of products)

so if you are looking to treat multiple products use the second way, but if you are looking to treat one single product, use the first one